Why am I seeing that Solaris 11.2 has slow disk reads or writes using dd?
I have this machine with Solaris 11.2, no updates :
uname -a
SunOS lab1 5.11 11.2 i86pc i386 i86pc

Which is quite bored out cause no any load.
I have migrated required data and I would like to test remotely one disk using dd on this host, without changing OS, packages, package versions, anything.
But it is too slow.
If I build a ZFS pool on top of this disk (no raid, no mirror) and dd to a file on top of the ZFS file system, it can reach datasheet disk maximum speed which is around 250 Mega Bytes per seconds.
Verified using iostat, not using dd values which are superior due to caching, I know.
But if I dd using these example commands :
/usr/gnu/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdsk/c4t3d0p0 oflag=nocache iflag=fullblock,nocache bs=2097152 count=32768

Or
/opt/csw/gnu/dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdsk/c4t3d0p0 oflag=nocache iflag=fullblock,nocache bs=2097152 count=32768

Or
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdsk/c4t3d0p0 oflag=nocache iflag=fullblock,nocache bs=2097152 count=32768

I got only 80 Mega bytes per seconds.
I have exprimented quite half an hundred of combinaisons of the three dd version and fullblock, nocache, block size, without success...
Incresing block size does not change the results, decreasing is slowing down.
oflag=direct seems not supported on these dd versions or this system.
The only difference I can cought was that when writing over ZFS, iostat report around 250 I/O per seconds while only 80 I/O with dd on the physical disk but in both cases iostat report nearly 100 % disk I/O busy, strange.
So I decided to go dtrace which show this:
sudo dtrace -s /usr/demo/dtrace/iothrough.d
  sd10 (/devices/pci@0,0/pci1849,1d02@6/disk@3,0:q)

           value  ------------- Distribution ------------- count
           16384 |                                         0
           32768 |                                         2
           65536 |@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  2260
          131072 |@                                        75
          262144 |                                         0

I mean, really I cannot dd with a block size greater than 65536?
Any guess to increase it and be able to reach disk speed?
Update 1 :
Running dd on a file on this brand new pool on this disk, destroying the pool, dd this physical disk, provide the same I/O size in both cases.
Which is really one Mega Byte (1024*1024), thanks to https://prefetch.net/articles/observeiodtk.html.
It seems to vary a little at the very beginning, kind of like the kernel or ZFS is searching for the best size in the ZFS case.
Wait too long and something happens into the kernel and the same dd command on the physical disk use then 64k block which provide only few Mega bytes per seconds...
With this workaround, which I did not realise it was, during my first tests steps (creating a pool on this disk, dd a file on it a little, destroying it, dd the disk), I can reach 80 Mega Bytes per seconds vs 250 (ZFS).
The only discrepancy really is 80 I/O per seconds versus 250 I/O per seconds reported by iostat. My best guest is that ZFS use SATA multiqueue.
I guess this issue follow up to latest Solaris, but nobody really dd anymore these days ; - (.
Investing more time is too much effort...
So I will go for dd a file into the pool which fit my purpose too.

PS :
/usr/gnu/bin/dd --version

dd (coreutils) 8.16
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, and Stuart Kemp.`

/opt/csw/gnu/dd --version

dd (coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


Written by Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, and Stuart Kemp.

Can't tell for Solaris dd as it does not seems to support version display.
Update 1 :
man dd | tail -5
SunOS 5.11          Last change: 16 Sep 1996                    8


Try oflag=sync instead, and/or a different filesystem? ZFS does make some things awkward to test. Some of the information in the answer here could help even if 11.2 doesn't support O_DIRECT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973798/7411885 . That said, running anything with "no updates" is just asking to run into bugs that have already been fixed

Thanks, but already tried with all possibilities of (x)flag=sync.

Thanks but no, ZFS is not making things awkward to demonstre what I wanted : it is able to I/O at 250 Mega Bytes per seconds, as per datasheet of the medium, to the medium, which prove it is possible.

Thanks, but already read this article during my researches, even if I may not have been able to correctly understood everything.

Finally, it seems to me that using /dev/rdsk in place of /dev/dsk seems to indicate raw !no cache!. I checked and the kernel cache is not growing using /dev/rdsk but it is using /dev/dsk. So I guess the way to use the Solaris "directio mode" kind of like O_DIRECT (oflag=direct) is to use /dev/rdsk.  So the limiting factor is the kernel cutting out dd blocks...

So I guess you may be right about updates, but it is not possible, no production licenses contracted, it is not a production platform but a lab...

Maybe someone, at some point in space and time, which has the knowledge to tune some Solaris kernel bits, will reach this question ; -)

iostat report around 250 I/O per seconds while only 80 I/O with dd on the physical disk  What is the physical disk?  Is it a spinning disk?  If so, 250 I/O per second is something only high-end 15000-RPM drives can reach.  80 I/O per second is about what a good 7200-RPM SATA drive will give you.  ZFS is probably buffering the write operations.

You mean iostat does not report real IOs ? If then what does it report ?

The disk is a spinning one : Seagate Barracuda Pro ST12000DM0007 that I want to dd.

New info : on each dd iteration the kernel is deciding a defferent block size. It is now mostly only doing 4k which is so slow...

I may have prodived the wrong dtrace, the one for zfs, I will retry and update the question with the comment answers

You mean iostat does not report real IOs If ZFS caches the IO operations and sends the operations to the disk in ways that minimize seeking, the actual number of IO operations could well exceed the number of random IO operations the disk can support.  And your suspicion that ZFS is using queuing might also be true.  Maybe there's something in the original DTrace Toolkit or its updates that can tell.

Remember dd alternates between reading and writing - and write() calls are done singly.  Between each write(), dd will read(), which takes time, and during that time the disk is spinning and the platter moves, so even if the heads don't have to seek for the next write(), there's likely to be some delay waiting for the proper sector to spin under the heads.  And any possible benefit for command queuing is left unused.
